# Assembly e C++ com Visual Studio 2015 e MASM x86/64

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, assembly

Boa noite.

Eu uso Visual Studio 2015 e costumo programar em linguagem assembly via `__asm`, mas eu ainda tenho dúvidas de como usar o MASM para criar código em assembly para x64. Preciso de ajuda para dar os primeiros passos.

Como crio funções em assembly num arquivo de formato "asm" e as chamo num arquivo de formato "cpp"?

Peço que mostre como proceder no seguinte exemplo, pois a partir dele eu vou pesquisando e aprendendo outros detalhes. Considere um projeto com dois arquivos, "Header.h" e "Source.cpp", programados para x86.

O arquivo "Header.h" tem a função `formula(a,b,ret2)`, que deseja-se escrever em assembly em um arquivo de código-fonte em assembly, por exemplo "AsmSource.asm".

```
// Header.h
// formula(a,b,ret2) = a*a + b*b
// *ret2 = ( a*b )/( a*a/b + b*b/a )

int __cdecl formula( int a , int b , int *ret2 ){
    int sqa , sqb , dv ;
    __asm {
        MOV eax , dword ptr [a]
        MUL eax
        MOV dword ptr [sqa] , eax
        DIV dword ptr [b]
        MOV dword ptr [dv] , eax
        MOV eax , dword ptr [b]
        MUL eax
        MOV dword ptr [sqb] , eax
        DIV dword ptr [a]
        ADD dword ptr [dv] , eax
        MOV eax , dword ptr [a]
        MUL dword ptr [b]
        DIV dword ptr [dv]
        MOV edi , [ret2]
        MOV [edi] , eax
        MOV eax , dword ptr [sqa]
        ADD eax , dword ptr [sqb]
    }
    return ;
}
```

O arquivo "Source.cpp" tem a função `main()` que faz a chamada da função que deve ser escrita em assembly.

```
// Source.cpp
# include <stdio.h>
# include <conio.h>
# include "Header.h"

int main(){
    int ret1 , ret2 ;
    ret1 = formula(12,16,&ret2) ;
    printf(" %i %i\n",ret1,ret2) ;
    _getch() ;
}
```

Se trocarmos o "Header.h" por um arquivo "AsmSource.asm", como devem estar escritos os arquivos "AsmSource.asm" e o "Source.cpp" de modo que se tenha o mesmo resultado? Preciso ter ideia do que muda ao sair do `__asm` para o arquivo de código assembly.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para criar arquivos com funções em *assembly* 64 bits utilizando o Visual Studio 2015 (Community):

- Clique com o botão direito do mouse no seu projeto, entre no menu `Build Dependencies` e depois em `Build Customizations...`. Na tela de customizações, selecione a opção `masm(.targets, .props)`:

[image: Tela de customizações do projeto no VS2015]

---

- No seu projeto, na pasta `Source Files`, adicione um novo item `Utility` do tipo `Text File (.txt)` (arquivo texto). Após adicionar, renomeie o arquivo de `.txt` para `.asm` (exemplo: `funcao.txt` para `funcao.asm`):

[image: Solution Explorer mostrando arquivo asm]

---

- Clique com o botão direito do mouse no arquivo `funcao.asm` e selecione `Properties`. Na janela de propriedades, altere o `Item Type` de `Text` para `Microsoft Macro Assembler`:

[image: Alteração do tipo do item]

---

- No código-fonte `C`, declare o protótipo das funções como `extern`. Se o programa é em `C++`, declare como `extern "C"`. No seu exemplo, o arquivo principal ficou assim:

```c
#include "stdafx.h"

// delcaração da função em assembly
extern "C" long long int formula(long long int a, long long int b, long long int *r2);

// Função em C que implementa o mesmo cálculo (apenas para teste)
long long int formula2(long long int a, long long int b, long long int *r2)
{
    *r2 = (a*b) / (a*a / b + b*b / a);
    return a*a + b*b;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    long long int ret1;
    long long int ret2;

    printf("inicio\n");
    // Execução em C
    ret1 = formula2(12, 16, &ret2);
    printf("Resultado C: ret1=%lld, ret2=%lld\n", ret1, ret2);

    // Execução em Assembly
    ret1 = formula(12, 16, &ret2);
    printf("Resultado ASM: ret1=%lld, ret2=%lld\n", ret1, ret2);

    printf("fim.\n");
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

O tipo `long long int` define as variáveis `ret1` e `ret2` como inteiros de 64bits.

Conforme a lógica que você deseja implementar, o tipo pode mudar e a forma como o código assembly será desenvolvido, também.

---

- No código-fonte *assembly*, declare as funções como `public`. Para o seu exemplo, o arquivo `funcao.asm` ficou assim:

```asm
.code
public formula    
;  formula(a,b,ret2) = a*a + b*b
; *ret2 = ( a*b )/( a*a/b + b*b/a )

formula proc
    mov         r11, rdx                ; r11 <- b
    xor         rdx, rdx                ; rdx = 0
    mov         rax, rcx
    imul        rax, rax                        
    mov         r9, rax                 ; r9 <- a^2

    mov         rax, r11
    imul        rax, rax                        
    mov         r10, rax                ; r10 <- b^2

    idiv        rcx
    mov         r12, rax                ; r12 <- b^2/a

    xor         rdx, rdx
    mov         rax, r9
    idiv        r11
    add         rax, r12
    mov         r13, rax                ; r13 <- b^2/a + a^2/b

    xor         rdx, rdx
    mov         rax, rcx
    imul        rax, r11
    idiv        r13
    mov         qword ptr [r8], rax     ; resultado em rax

    mov         rax, r9
    add         rax, r10
    ret
formula endp

end
```

---

Em *assembly* 64 bits, a passagem de parâmetros, declaração de variáveis locais,   retorno de funções, etc. são diferentes do *assembly* de 32 bits.

Seguem alguns links (em inglês) que falam sobre o assunto (para programação `Windows`, o principal é o primeiro link):

- [MS - Overview of x64 Calling Conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235286.aspx)
- [Wikipedia - x86-64 calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#x86-64_calling_conventions)
- [Intel - System V Application Binary Interface (PDF)](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/article/402129/mpx-linux64-abi.pdf)

---

O resultado, após a execução do programa:

```
inicio
Resultado C: ret1=400, ret2=6
Resultado ASM: ret1=400, ret2=6
fim.
```

---

### Edit

Em resposta ao comentário, para compilar um código misto (32 e 64bits), conforme o *target* definido no VS2015:

- Clique com o botão direito do mouse no arquivo `funcao.asm` e entre em `Properties`. Na janela de propriedades, altere (caso seja necessário) os items: `Configuration` para `All Configurations` e `Platform` para `Win32` ou `Active(Win32)` (se este plataforma já estiver selecionada)
- Altere o item `Excluded From Build` para `Yes`

[image: Propriedades do arquivo funcao.asm]

Com esta alteração, o arquivo `funcao.asm` só será compilado quando a plataforma estiver definida para 64 bits.

---

No código fonte, utilize a macro `_WIN64` para definir o protótipo das funções como `extern` para 64bits, ou com *assembly inline* (por exemplo) para 32bits.

O **ponto importante** (se possível) é: manter o protótipo das funções idênticas tanto para 32 quanto para 64bits.

Após as alterações, o código-fonte em `C` fica da seguinte forma:

```c
#include "stdafx.h"

#ifdef _WIN64
// Código 64 bits
// delcaração da função em assembly
extern "C" long long int formula(long long int a, long long int b, long long int *r2);

#else
// Código 32 bits
// Inline
long long int _cdecl formula(long long int a, long long int b, long long int *ret2) {
    int sqa, sqb, dv;
    int ret_local; // Acrescentei esta variável
    __asm {
        mov     eax, dword ptr[a]
        mul     eax
        mov     dword ptr[sqa], eax
        div     dword ptr[b]
        mov     dword ptr[dv], eax
        mov     eax, dword ptr[b]
        mul     eax
        mov     dword ptr[sqb], eax
        div     dword ptr[a]
        add     dword ptr[dv], eax
        mov     eax, dword ptr[a]
        mul     dword ptr[b]
        div     dword ptr[dv]
        mov     [ret2], eax         ; Aqui, o código estava incorreto
        mov     eax, dword ptr[sqa]
        add     eax, dword ptr[sqb]
        mov     [ret_local], eax    ; Armazena o retorno
    }
    return (long long int) ret_local;
}
#endif // _WIN64

// Função em C que implementa o mesmo cálculo (apenas para teste)
long long int formula2(long long int a, long long int b, long long int *r2)
{
    *r2 = (a*b) / (a*a / b + b*b / a);
    return a*a + b*b;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    long long int ret1;
    long long int ret2;

    printf("inicio\n");
    // Execução em C
    ret1 = formula2(12, 16, &ret2);
    printf("Resultado C: ret1=%lld, ret2=%lld\n", ret1, ret2);

    // Execução em Assembly
    ret1 = formula(12, 16, &ret2);
    printf("Resultado ASM: ret1=%lld, ret2=%lld\n", ret1, ret2);

    printf("fim.\n");
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

---

Obs: fiz apenas uma pequena correção no código *inline* e acrescentei uma variável local para retornar o resultado da função.

O resultado da execução é o mesmo informado na resposta acima.

---

Obs2: Há outras formas, possivelmente melhores, de organizar o código misto (32 e 64bits) dentro da `Solution` do VS2015. Esta resposta é apenas um "ponto de partida" para mostrar como compilar o código misto.

Comment: Obrigado. Vou testar tudo isso.

Comment: Deu certo ao compilar para x64, mas não quando compilei para x86 (mesmo colocando condicional "# ifdef _WIN64" para decidir se usa "extern" ou "include"). Tem alguma maneira de fazer o compilador selecionar qual será o código utilizado de acordo com a arquitetura sem dar vários erros?

Comment: Os erros foram (somente) na compilação do arquivo `funcao.asm`?

Comment: Eu editei a resposta. Por favor, verifique se está ok :)

Comment: Os vários erros foram associados ao arquivo ".asm", provavelmente estava interpretando como código C++ pois os primeiros erros se referiam aos comentários pós ponto e vírgula.

Comment: Uma coisa que eu gostaria de fazer é usar "# ifndef" no arquivo ".asm" e lá escrever os códigos x86 e x64. É possível?

Comment: @RHERWOLF acredito que não seja possível, pois os formatos dos objetos gerados para x86 e x64 são diferentes e a diretiva do pré-processador só irá mudar o conteúdo do arquivo e não o seu formato. Para analisar o formato gerado, experimente entrar no diretório onde está o arquivo `funcao.obj` e digitar o comando `dumpbin /all funcao.obj`. Você verá que o tipo do arquivo é `8664 machine (x64)`, por isso, o *linker* não conseguirá ligar o objeto 64bits com os demais objetos gerados pelo `C` (32bits).

Comment: Ok. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: @RHERWOLF De nada :)